# Hey, anyone who can can help with characterization of Orthogonal Projections?

Tags: functional-analysis

(Characterization of Orthogonal Projections) $P: H \longrightarrow H$, $P^2 = P$, $Q:=I - P$, $\ker P = \mathop{\rm  ran} Q$. Show that: 
$$(i)\|Pf  \| = \| f \|  \quad for \quad f \in H$$
  $$(ii) F:=\mathop{\rm  ran} P \quad is \quad closed \quad and \quad P=P_F$$
                                                                    Solution: $\mathbf{(i)} \Rightarrow \mathbf{(ii)}$.  $\| Pf \| \leq \| f \|$ ( for $f \in H$ ) yields $P$ is continuous, so $Q = I - P$ is continuous. Hence
$$
\ker Q = {x: (I - P)(x) = 0} = {x: Px = x}
$$
is closed in $H$.

If $x \in \mathop{\rm  ran} P$, then $x = P(y)$ for $y \in H$.
$$
Px = P(P(y)) = P^2y = P(y) = x,
$$
so $Px = x$,  $x \in \ker Q$. If $x \in \ker Q$, so $x = Px$, $x \in \mathop{\rm  ran} P$. $ \mathop{\rm  ran} P = \ker Q$. Thus $F:= \mathop{\rm  ran} P$ is closed subset in $H$.
It is a correct solution or not? Please help.

Comment: Hi there. Would you kindly edit your question to make use of MathJax? See: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference  This will go a long way to make your question more digestible.

Comment: You also seem to have mistyped something, you wrote $\lVert{Pf\rVert} = \lVert{f \rVert}$ for all $f \in H$. This can't be right since it would imply $P = \text{Id}$.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is correct except for the fact that you didn't actually prove that $P = P_F$. For this you need to prove that $Px \in F$ and $x-Px \in F^\perp$. Of course the first statement is trivial, and the second is not much more difficult but should still be stated to be complete.

Now allow me to give you some constructive criticism. Try to use more words and complete phrases in your arguments. Your proofs will become much nicer to read. For phrases like these:

"...so $Px = x$,  $x \in \ker Q$. If $x \in \ker Q$, so $x = Px$, $x \in \mathop{\rm  ran} P$"

are pretty awful to read. It took me a while to understand what you were saying there. Consider this complete proof to your proposition:

First we prove that $\ker P^\perp = F$ where $F = \text{ran } P$. An immediate result of this is that $F$ is closed. Take any $x \in \ker P^\perp$. Note that we have $x-Px \in \text{ran } (I-P) = \ker P$, so we find
$$
0 = \langle x-Px, x\rangle = \lVert x \rVert^2 - \langle Px, x \rangle.
$$
By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we have
$$
\lVert x \rVert^2 = \langle Px, x \rangle \leq \lVert x \rVert \lVert Px \rVert \leq \lVert x \rVert^2.
$$
So we conclude that $\lVert Px \rVert^2 = \lVert x \rVert^2 = \langle Px, x \rangle^2$.
But then we find that
$$
\lVert x-Px \rVert^2 = \lVert x\rVert^2 -2\text{Re }(\langle Px,x \rangle) + \lVert Px\rVert^2 = 0.
$$
As a result we have $x= Px \in \text{ran } P$ or $\ker P^\perp \subset F$. Conversely if $x \in F$, we can write $x=x_1 + x_2$ with $x_1 \in \ker P$ and $x_2 \in \ker P^\perp$. Now note that $Px_2 = x_2$ since $x_2 \in F$ by our previous argument. So we find
$$
x = Px = Px_1 + Px_2= x_2.
$$
From this we conclude that $x_1 = 0$ and thus $x \in F$. At last we prove that $P = P_F$. Note that it is sufficient to show that $x - Px \in F^\perp$ for all $x \in H$. But by our previous argument we have that $F^\perp = \ker P$, so the result is immediate and this concludes our proof.

Comment: Let $y \in F$, then the function $$ f(t) \rightarrow \| (x-Px) +ty \|^2$$ have a minimum $t=0$. 

On the other hand  $$f(t)=\| x-Px \|^2 +2t Re(y - Px ) +t^2 \| y \| ,$$ so  we  obtain  $$0 = f^`(0)=2 Re(y|x-Px).$$ Moreover $$
Im(y|x-Px)= Re(iy|x-Px)=0
$$
 because  $iy \in F$. That means $x-Px \in F^{\perp}$ 

Is it  good or not?

Comment: You don't actually argue why $f$ has a minimum. Furthermore it is usually best to avoid arguments involving derivatives where possible. Often they can be replaced by arguments only using infima and suprema and the like, which are much easier. I edited my answer to post a complete proof to your question, I hope it helps.

Comment: You're welcome. If you have any more questions about the proof, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

$$(ii) F:=\mathop{\rm  ran} P \quad is \quad closed \quad and \quad  P=P_F,$$
$$ (iii)\mathop{\rm  ran} P \perp \ker P,$$
  $$(iv) \langle Pf, \quad g\rangle = \langle f, \quad Pg \rangle  \quad for \quad all \quad f,g \in H.$$
Now we proof that $\mathbf{(iii)} \Rightarrow \mathbf{(iv)}$. We assume that $\mathop{\rm  ran} P \perp \ker P$. Fix $f,g \in H$. Then we obtain
$$
P(Pf-f) = P^2f - Pf = Pf - Pf = 0.
$$
Hence $Pf - f \in \ker P$. Next $Pg \in \mathop{\rm  ran} P$, whence
$$
\langle Pf - f, Pg \rangle = 0, \quad \text{that is}\quad \langle Pf, Pg \rangle = \langle f, Pg \rangle.
$$
 In a similar way we obtain
$$
\langle Pf, Pg - g \rangle = 0, \quad  \text{that is} \quad \langle Pf, Pg \rangle = \langle Pf, g \rangle,
$$
which means that $\langle Pf, g \rangle = \langle f, Pg \rangle$.
Is this proof correct? How to proof that $\mathbf{(ii)} \Rightarrow \mathbf{(iii)}$ ? Any suggestion?